# Docker Compose Getting Started guide

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm following the Docker Compose getting started guide (https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) and I've followed the guide exactly. My `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml`, and all other files in the directory are exactly as they appear in the guide.

However, when I attempt to run `docker-compose up`, the web service exits immediately with an exit code of 2, and an error message:

```
web_1    | python: can't open file 'app.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Building and running an image works fine if the run by itself, i.e.

```
docker build -t composetestweb .
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 composetestweb
```

The website spits out an error, but it does respond.

Inspecting the composed container appears to present the correct information: the command, mounted folders, and working directory are all correct.

I'm using Docker Machine on Windows 7 with VirtualBox 4.3.38. For the record, I haven't had any problems with any other Docker guides up to this point.

Comment: Can you add your docker-compose.yml and folder structure please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common cause of this error is using `docker-machine` and a project output of your `$HOME` directory. `docker-machine` will only create a Virtualbox shared folder for the home directory, so if your project is outside of that directory the `volumes:` used in the `docker-compose` will not work.

You have the following options:

- move the project to a directory under your home directory
- add another shared folder to virtualbox for the folder where you store your projects
- don't use `volumes:`, removing it from the `docker-compose`

Comment: Moving the directory worked for me. I was doing all of my work out of a directory on my machine C:\DockerWorkspace. This worked fine when running containers without compose.
Curiously, adding C:\DockerWorkspace as a shared folder in VirtualBox didn't fix the issue.

Comment: The path you use for the shared folder would have to be `/DockerWorkspace` I think, is that what you used?