# Docker getting started 3 - Docker Compose unable to connect - connection refused

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am following the Docker Getting Started Tutorials and I am stuck at [part 3](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#your-first-docker-composeyml-file) (Docker Compose). I am operating on a **fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installation**. Following the tutorial from [part 1](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) and [part 2](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#define-a-container-with-dockerfile), except logging in to a Docker account and pushing the newly created image to a remote repository.

The Docker image file and python file are the same as in [part 2](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#define-a-container-with-dockerfile), and the .yml file is the same as [part 3](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#your-first-docker-composeyml-file) (I copy-pasted them with vim).

I can deploy a stack with docker compose apparently fine. However, when getting to the part where I am supposed to send a request via curl, I get the following response

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

This is the output of `docker service ls` right after returning from `docker stack deploy`:

```
ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE               PORTS
m3ux2u3i6cpv        getstartedlab_web   replicated          1/5                 username/repo:tag   *:80->80/tcp
```

This is the output of `docker container ls` (fired right after `docker service ls`):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES
bd870fcb64f4        username/repo:tag   "python app.py"     7 seconds ago       Up 1 second         80/tcp              getstartedlab_web.2.p9v9p34kztmu8rvht3ndg2xtb
db73404d495f        username/repo:tag   "python app.py"     7 seconds ago       Up 1 second         80/tcp              getstartedlab_web.1.z3o2t10oiidtzofsonv9cwcvd
```

While `docker ps` returns no lines.

And this is the output of `docker network ls`:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                   DRIVER              SCOPE
5776b070996c        bridge                 bridge              local
47549d9b2e88        docker_gwbridge        bridge              local
59xa0454g133        getstartedlab_webnet   overlay             swarm
e27f62ede27d        host                   host                local
ramvt1h8ueg7        ingress                overlay             swarm
f0fe862c5dcc        none                   null                local
```

I can still run the image as a single container and get the **expected result**, i.e. **being able to connect to it via browser or curl and get an error message related to Redis**, but I do not understand why **it doesn't work when I deploy a stack**.

As far as Ubuntu firewall settings are concerned, I have tinkered with none since the installation, and as for Docker and Docker Compose, I have only followed the steps in the "getting started" tutorials in chapters 1-to-3, including downloading Docker Compose binaries and changing permissions with chmod as described. I also added my user to the Docker group so I don't have to sudo every time I need to run a command. I am not behind a proxy server (I am running all tests in local) and I haven't tinkered with any defaults either.

I think this may be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47139364/how-to-use-curl-4-http-localhost-in-the-docker-part-3-tutorial), though it hasn't been answered nor commented on yet. It is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471788/docker-compose-getting-started-guide), as I am following a different tutorial.

**UPDATE:**
As it was, I was using EXACTLY the same docker-compose.yml file. The key issue was a name mismatch with the docker image name, as is visible in the `docker service ls` output. I thank Janshair Khan for the inspiration. What is strange is for there to be a *username/repo* image created apparently 9 months ago:

```
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<my getting-started image>
python               2.7-slim            4fd30fc83117        7 weeks ago         138MB
hello-world          latest              f2a91732366c        2 months ago        1.85kB
username/repo        <none>              c7f5ee4d4030        9 months ago        182MB
```

Comment: Are you using the same `docker-compose.yml` or you modified something?

Comment: It's not clear from your update. Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, problem solved. I had left `username/repo` in the image field in the .yml file, and so I was deploying a wrong image, not providing the expected behaviour. I didn't expect there would be an image with such a name to pull.